# VPN clients gets disconnected in my machine very frequently (2 or 3 times per hour). clients I'm using are FortiClient VPN and Cisco AnyConnect VPN

Tags: vpn

VPN clients gets disconnected in my machine very frequently (2 or 3 times per hour). clients I'm using are FortiClient VPN and Cisco AnyConnect VPN.

Log file from FortiClient is as below,

```
3/8/2022 2:04:27 PM info sslvpn date=2022-03-08 time=14:04:26 logver=1 id=96600 type=securityevent subtype=sslvpn eventtype=status level=info uid=556CBFD17961472AB2443601856E703C devid=FCT8000116156976 hostname=DESKTOP-XXXXXX pcdomain=N/A deviceip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx devicemac=01-05-9b-3c-7v-00 site=N/A fctver=7.0.2.0090 fgtserial=FCT8000116156976 emsserial=N/A os="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional Edition, 64-bit (build 19041)" user=xxxxxxxxxxx@AzureAD msg="SSLVPN tunnel status" vpnstate=connected vpntunnel=vpn.xxxxxxxx.co.uk  3/8/2022 2:17:26 PM error sslvpn FortiSslvpn: 8888: error: poll_send_ssl -SSL_get_error(): 5, try:1 3/8/2022 2:17:26 PM error sslvpn FortiSslvpn: 8888: error: poll_send_ssl - WSAGetLastError():2745, try:1 3/8/2022 2:17:26 PM error sslvpn FortiSslvpn: 8888: error: poll_send_ssl -data size: 50, try:1 3/8/2022 2:17:26 PM error sslvpn FortiSslvpn: 8888: [handle_driver_read_event]: error: poll_send 3/8/2022 2:18:55 PM info sslvpn FortiSslvpn: 12472: Ras: connection to fortissl terminated
```

In windows events logs following messages appear,

```
Connectivity state in standby: Disconnected. Reason: Policy Setting
7026 - Dump after return from D3 after cmd
The system is entering connected standby. Reason: Idle timeout
```

I was not in an idle state for a long time when disconnecting.
There are no internet connectivity issues for me.

Comment: Hi. Could you please unwrap the text in log, so it becomes human readable? :-) putting the entire lig in a code block does also help. :-)